# How can I copy only a specific file when using cmake --install?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

Whenever I edit any file in the `qt` source and recompile, I need to call `cmake --install .` to make it copy the updated file from the source directory to the destination, like:

[image]

It spends a lot of time iterating through thousand files checking which are not updated:

```
-- Up-to-date: D:/Qt/Debug/include/QtDesigner/6.4.0/QtDesigner/private/qdesigner_formeditorcommand_p.h
-- Up-to-date: D:/Qt/Debug/include/QtDesigner/6.4.0/QtDesigner/private/qdesigner_formwindowcommand_p.h
-- Up-to-date: D:/Qt/Debug/include/QtDesigner/6.4.0/QtDesigner/private/qdesigner_formwindowmanager_p.h
-- Up-to-date: D:/Qt/Debug/include/QtDesigner/6.4.0/QtDesigner/private/qdesigner_introspection_p.h
-- Up-to-date: D:/Qt/Debug/include/QtDesigner/6.4.0/QtDesigner/private/qdesigner_membersheet_p.h
-- Up-to-date: D:/Qt/Debug/include/QtDesigner/6.4.0/QtDesigner/private/qdesigner_menu_p.h
-- Up-to-date: D:/Qt/Debug/include/QtDesigner/6.4.0/QtDesigner/private/qdesigner_menubar_p.h
-- Up-to-date: D:/Qt/Debug/include/QtDesigner/6.4.0/QtDesigner/private/qdesigner_propertycommand_p.h
...
```

How i could specify directly what file it should copy?

For example, copy only the `Qt6Widgetsd.dll`?

I tried:

```
D:\Qt\qt-everywhere-src-6.4.0>cmake --install qtbase\bin\Qt6Widgetsd.dll
CMake Error: Error processing file: D:/Qt/qt-everywhere-src-6.4.0/qtbase/bin/Qt6Widgetsd.dll/cmake_install.cmake
```

Comment: this image should be text instead of an image: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can install specific components which are configured as part of the project configuration (see the `component` argument of [`install()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html) and the [`--component`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-install-component) argument of `cmake --install`), and the only way to only install a specific file as part of `cmake --install` is to configure that file to be part of its own installation component and specify only that component to be installed as part of the install commandline call.

Note that if you want to change the verbosity level of installation status messages such as "Up-to-date", you can use [`CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE.html).

Comment: Theres not any command to install only the modified files other than `-- install .` which iterate all existing files?

Comment: @Joey ... what you are describing seems to be what you are already getting, based on the "up-to-date" messages.

Comment: I mean a way to dont spend a lot of time iterating over all files, and copy directly the modified.

Comment: @Joey not that I know of other than what I've already written in my answer post.

Comment: @Joey Probably the only thing you could improve would be to disable the output you don't need, see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE.html Other than that you're very likely out of luck. If would be quite hard for cmake to catch every single scenario; (Using different install `--prefix`es. Modifying the install logic and reconfiguring the cmake project. The user modifying the target dir of the installation manually. Only some components being installed during installation. ...)